# How can I optimally rotate accelerometer readings so that the integrated velocity ends up correct?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, rotation, data-analysis, gyroscopes

I attached an accelerometer (with gyro/magnometer) to a curling rock and threw it down the sheet of ice.  The accelerometer was not flat, and it did not travel significantly in the $z$ direction.  I am attempting to construct the $x$ and $y$ velocity by integrating the accelerometer readings after processing them through a 4d rotation matrix.  To do this I just selected a point during the recording where the rock was not moving, and computed the rotational matrix needed to rotate that vector to be (0,0,1).  I then applied that same rotation to all readings, and integrated.  Here is the calculated velocity right from the accelerometer output:

[image: before rotation]

After rotation I get a steady velocity at the end which is better, but the velocity does not end up as 0.  Here is that graph:

[image: after rotation]

Here is the z acceleration after rotation:

[image: accell after rotation].

Ideally this would be 1 for all values, but it is not.  Can anyone suggest a better way to do this calculation or find the rotation matrix so that I end up with 0 velocity at the end?

Comment: It looks like your raw accelerometer readings are sending your gravitational acceleration to be half in x and half in z directions. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the accelerometer was not level.  Hence why I trying to find the optimal rotation to account for this.

Comment: Why should the $z$ acceleration be one? I would expect it to be zero if the stone isn't moving in the $z$ direction. When the stone is not moving, shouldn't the acceleration vector be $\overrightarrow{0}$? Why did you choose to calibrate it to (0,0,1)?

Comment: z axis is up and down.  Units are Gs.  Even when the rock is not moving, Gravity is always  on :)